# fixing the wrong output on certain section

Tags: c, switch-statement

In my instructions given, close to the end, the employee data must display each column in order as 222, 666, 444 and 555 after removing column '333' earlier. I need help with getting column '666' into column '333's original place.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define SIZE 4

#include <stdio.h>

struct employee {

int number;
int age;
double salary;
};

int main(void) {
struct employee emp[SIZE] = { { 0,0,0 } }; //struct w/ array
int option = 1; //option variable
int nEmp = 0; //counting how many employee we have so far
int empIndex = 0;
int i, check, sNumber;


printf("---=== EMPLOYEE DATA ===---\n\n");

while (option != 0) {
 printf("1. Display Employee Information\n");
 printf("2. Add Employee\n");
 printf("3. Update Employee Salary\n");
 printf("4. Remove Employee\n");
 printf("0. Exit\n\n");
 printf("Please select from the above options: ");
 scanf("%d", &option);
 printf("\n");

 switch (option)
 {
 case 1: //print employee information
  printf("EMP ID  EMP AGE EMP SALARY\n");
  printf("======  ======= ==========\n");

  for (i = 0; i < nEmp; i++) {

   if (emp[i].number > 0 && emp[i].age > 0 && emp[i].salary)

   printf("%d       %d   %.2lf\n", emp[i].number, emp[i].age, emp[i].salary);
  }
  printf("\n");

  break;

 case 2: //add employee
  printf("Adding Employee\n");
  printf("===============\n");

  if (nEmp < SIZE) {

   empIndex = 0;

   while ((emp[empIndex].number != 0) && (empIndex < SIZE)) {
    empIndex++;
   }

   printf("Enter Employee ID: ");
   scanf("%d", &emp[empIndex].number);
   printf("Enter Employee Age: ");
   scanf("%d", &emp[empIndex].age);
   printf("Enter Employee Salary: ");
   scanf("%lf", &emp[empIndex].salary);
   printf("\n");
   nEmp++; 

  }
  else {

   printf("ERROR!!! Maximum Number of Employees Reached\n\n");
  }

  break;

 case 3: //update employee
  printf("Update Employee Salary\n");
  printf("======================\n");

  if (nEmp == 0) { //alternative just in case there is no employee yet
   printf("\nNo employee to update\n\n");

   break;
  }
  do
  {
   check = 1;

   printf("Enter Employee ID: ");
   scanf("%d", &sNumber);

   for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
   {
    if (emp[i].number == sNumber) 

     break;

    else if (i == nEmp - 1) 

     printf("*** ERROR: Employee ID not found! ***\n");
   }
   if (i != nEmp) {

    printf("The current salary is %.2f\n", emp[i].salary);
    printf("Enter Employee New Salary: ");
    scanf("%lf", &emp[i].salary);
    check = 0;
    printf("\n");
   }
  } while (check);

  break;
 case 4: //remove employee

  printf("Remove Employee\n");
  printf("===============\n");

  if (nEmp == 0) { //in case there is no employee yet

   printf("\nNo employee to remove\n\n");

   break;
  }
  do
  {
   check = 1;

   printf("Enter Employee ID: ");
   scanf("%d", &sNumber);

   for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
   {
    if (emp[i].number == sNumber) 

     break;

    else if (i == nEmp - 1) 

     printf("*** ERROR: Employee ID not found! ***\n");
   }

   if (i != nEmp) {
    check = 0;

    printf("Employee %d will be removed\n\n", emp[i].number);
    emp[i].number = 0;
    emp[i].age = 0;
    emp[i].salary = 0.0;

    nEmp -= 1;
   }

  } while (check);

  break;

 case 0: //exiting process

  printf("Exiting Employee Data Program. Good Bye!!!\n");

  break;

 default: //not valid option input

  printf("ERROR: Incorrect Option: Try Again\n\n");

  break;
 }
 //if (option != 0) option = -1;
}
return 1;
}
```

I expect FINAL output to be:

```
EMP ID  EMP AGE EMP SALARY
======  ======= ==========
222       22   22222.22
666       66   66666.66
444       44   44444.44
555       55   55555.55
```

and NOT (what I'm currently getting)

```
EMP ID  EMP AGE EMP SALARY
======  ======= ==========
222       22   22222.22
444       44   44444.44
555       55   55555.55
666       66   66666.66
```

before exiting the program.

Comment: You have explicitly coded the removal as shifting the "tail" of the array into the gap, so that behaviour shouldn't be a surprise. If you want a "fast" removal, just move the last item into the gap: `nEmp--; emp[i] = emp[nEmp];`

Comment: do i put that in the first case, right before the else, but just replace the enum++ with this?

Comment: That's the code for option 4 after you have checked that there is a valid `i`. There's another problem when you print the employees (option 1): Your loop condition should test the actual number of employees, not the maximum: `I < nEmp` instead of `i < SIZE`. Look at Aconcagua's answer, which is very detailed.

Comment: Off-topic: Consider dropping the while loop around the selection of the user to be deleted. As is, the user cannot decide not to delete an employee any more (e. g. because of accidentally having typed the wrong command). Same for case 3.

Comment: @M Oehm ok, fixed the option 1, now, for option 4 you want me to delete that block and replace it with this  ?

Comment: Look at Aconcagua's answer: That `if (i != nEmp)` block replaces your `if (i != nEmp)` block.

Comment: @Aconcagua this still doesn't give me the correct output. right after removing employee '333' the columns shown now is '222' '555' and '444' in that order when it should be '222' '444' and then '555'. then, after adding column '666', the column order is now '222' '555' '444' and then '666', when it should be '222' 666' 444' and then '555'. why is this?

Comment: and if i get rid of the while statements, the code gives me errors, that before the break statement, the while statement is expected!

Comment: I've updated the code, so you guys can get a better look at where I'm at with the tips you gave me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your problem is actually this. Originally, your array looked something like the following:

```
EMP ID  EMP AGE EMP SALARY
======  ======= ========== 
222       22   22222.22 
333       33   33333.33 
444       44   44444.44 
555       55   55555.55
```

You wish to change this to the following:

```
EMP ID  EMP AGE EMP SALARY
======  ======= ========== 
222       22   22222.22 
666       66   66666.66 
444       44   44444.44 
555       55   55555.55
```

In that case, what I suggest you do is when deleting the column with 333, you replace all the struct members with 0, (0 in this case would mean that column is empty) instead of moving the columns. In your code for adding new employees, check to see if any employee number is 0. That will give you the new location of where you have to add in a new employee.

So essentially, make the following change on your "delete Employee" code

```
if (i != nEmp) {
    check = 0;

    printf("Employee %d will be removed\n\n", emp[i].number);
    emp[i].number = 0;
    emp[i].age = 0;
    emp[i].salary = 0.0;

    nEmp -= 1;
   }
```

and make this change to your "adding Employee" code

```
  if (nEmp < SIZE) {

   int empIndex = 0; //new variable to find the next possible location to store the employee

   while ((emp[empIndex].number != 0) && (empIndex < SIZE)) {       
        empIndex++;
   }

   printf("Enter Employee ID: ");
   scanf("%d", &emp[empIndex].number);
   printf("Enter Employee Age: ");
   scanf("%d", &emp[empIndex].age);
   printf("Enter Employee Salary: ");
   scanf("%lf", &emp[empIndex].salary);
   printf("\n");
   nEmp++;
  }
```

Make sure to use `empIndex` instead of `nEmp` to store the new employee. Note that if you delete an employee, but you do not add back any employees, you will be printing out zeroes for that entry you deleted. Also, note that this means you need to print out all the members within the array instead of just the first few, since you could potentially have an employee in the last location of the array, but none in the middle.

Comment: ok, its a little bit better, but still is wrong. Now, as I am done removing column '333' it also removes column '555' aswell. so the columns shown after removal of 333 is '222' and '444' in that order, missing column '555' obviously. Then something very strange happens when i add column '666'.  the columns showing after that is strangely enough; columns '222', '444' and '555' reappears in that order, but now column '666' is gone. i am updating the code for you guys to further experiment with...

Comment: Well, as to why 555 doesn't get printed out, it's because you are using for (i = 0; i < nEmp; i++) when printing it. Change it back for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++). You need SIZE now because you need to go through the entire array to see if there's an employee there

Comment: you mean just change the nEmp to SIZE in the case 4 loop or the other loop as well that also contains nEmps?

Comment: As to why 666 doesn't appear, I purposely defined the empIndex variable inside if (nEmp < SIZE) {...} portion. You are currently defining it outside of the switch case. The problem with that is that it doesn't reset back to 0. It needs to go back to 0 in order to start searching in the array from the beginning. Just add empIndex = 0; before you begin the search.

Comment: i understand, but i'd lose marks if my variables were declared outside of the main (where all the other variables are declared). its an absolute specification

Comment: @Aaron yes, you should change nEmp to SIZE in all cases. As long as you need search through the entire array

Comment: @Aaron Then, you can leave where you defined empIndex. Just make sure to have empIndex = 0; statement before you begin the search in your adding employee code.

Comment: ok, so you helped me out with the final section. the final part displays columns '222' '666' '444' and '555' all correctly. However, that just leaves 1 more wrong thing, the mater of deleting column '333'. it still displays '222' and '444' in that order, nothing changed, '555' is still a no-show. Updating the code (hopefully) for the last time now!

Comment: You need to change for (i = 0; i < nEmp; i++) to for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) in case 1 (and also anywhere else where you have used nEmp) for the reason I mentioned above

Comment: thank you very much. I noticed my mistake and corrected, and everything now works buttery smooth & correctly. I sincerely appreciate the help! Thank you thank you thank you

Comment: @Aaron No problem. If my answer has helped you, I will be very grateful if you could accept it

Comment: could you upvote my post please? I have most definitely accepted this as the true answer. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop (`for (i = searchedI; i < nEmp; i++) { ... }`) is moving all elements one position to front. To get the desired result, just move the last element to the position to be deleted (code below shows the complete if block that remains):

```
if (i != nEmp)
{
    check = 0;
    printf("Employee %d will be removed\n\n", emp[i].number);

    --nEmp; // doing this first spares you additional subtractons later...
    if (i != nEmp) // last element does not have to be moved...
        emp[i] = emp[nEmp];
    emp[nEmp].number = 0; // actually redundant
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused, but understand this code you have shown me. Where do i put this exactly?  I apologize, but I have 2 for loops in case 3 & 4. so which for loop do you want me to delete/replace?

Comment: understood. but where exactly do i put this code block?

Comment: @Aaron `for (i = searchedI; i < nEmp; i++)` – thought it was obvious as it's this loop that is moving the elements...

Comment: do i also have to remove the nEmps -= 1 at the bottom of that line, or should i leave it?

Comment: Well, sure you need to remove. It's equivalent to `--nEmps`, if you didn't, you'd remove two elements...